# Correct way to Download CSV File at the Client Side Vue App

Tags: download, axios, filesaver.js

I have a Vue application in which I have an "downloadCsv" method. When a button is pressed, this method is invoked and the following rest GET call is made:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "downloadCsv")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportSubmitted() throws IOException {

    //Generates CSV file and returns fileName
    String filePath = myService.generateCSV();

    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(filePath));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + "data.csv" + "\"")
        .body(resource);
}
```

When I call this endpoint directly, i.e. `localhost:8080/downloadCsv` in the browser(chrome), the csv is downloaded.

However, when I call this endpoint from within my Vue app on click, i.e.:

```javascript
  axios.get(endpoint)
            .then(result => {
        const blob = new Blob([result], {type: 'text/csv'});
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'download.csv');
    });
```

I am unable to have the browser download the file.

What is the correct way to call a rest endpoint that returns a file and download it within the browser in Vue?

Comment: _"I am unable to have the browser download the file"_ <- can you expand on this? How does it _"not work"_? Are there any errors in your browser console? How is `result` generated? What type is `result`?

Comment: Can you please read my questions again; I didn't ask you about the HTTP response status

Comment: @Phil I have updated the question on how result is generated. I have verified in the browser that it is calling the `/downloadCsv` api.

Comment: Have you tried setting `responseType: 'blob'` in your Axios request, eg `axios.get(endpoint, { responseType: 'blob' })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle file download from ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/wiki/Saving-a-remote-file